# Dealing with two RecyclerViews

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I am developing a cinema app, but I want to use 2 RecyclerViews. one has successfully loaded, it contains the list of cinemas. I want When the user clicks on any of the cinemas, the app loads another list of RecyclerView containing the movies at that cinema.

How can I deal with 2 RecyclerViews?

I'm new to Android. Below is the link to the sample of codes:

[RecyclerView Item to Load Another RecyclerView with Nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812637/recyclerview-item-to-load-another-recyclerview-with-nested-json)

Comment: @halfer how can i do this thing , i have tried but it has failed

Comment: Fixed grammar errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question @prune thanks for the correction,  but you can click in the link to see the further description of the question.

Comment: You should probably delete this question, since all it really does is to point to the other version.